# Update MongoDB document with Arrayfilters when inner array has only another array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below is my nested array and I want to update a value in inner array. The scenario is similar to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309166/mongodb-update-with-array-filters?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But, I have only inner array inside first array. So , I am not sure how to specify the identifier for the first array

```
{
    "RequestID": "A22A8D43FE5D8D1409D5984003AB5609",
    "OPC_REQUEST_ID": [{
            "B69BF2DCEBB932A2665920BE14BA14C5": [{
                "Message": "Some message ",
                "Time": "2020-02-25T07:30:52Z",
                "bug": [
                    "27571088",
                    "7452257"
                ],
            "label": [
                    "No Label"
                ],
                "score": -0.5106
            }]
        },
        {
            "8E0FCBBF92D7226ADB6F3DB465DDA7F4": [{
                "Message": "Some message",
                "Time": "2020-02-25T07:31:52Z",
                "bug": [],
                "label": [
                    "No Label"
                ],
                "score": -0.7184
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried below query, but the key for the identifier "j" is another array , so I am not sure how specify key/value for "j" in the "arrayFilters"

```
db.requestid.update({'RequestID':'A22A8D43FE5D8D1409D5984003AB5609'},{'$set':{'OPC_REQUEST_ID.$[j].8E0FCBBF92D7226ADB6F3DB465DDA7F4.$[k].score' : '0'}},
{arrayFilters:[{'j.OPC_REQUEST_ID' :'8E0FCBBF92D7226ADB6F3DB465DDA7F4' }, {'k.Message' : 'Some message'}]})
}
```

I want to edit the "score" in the second array from -0.7184 to 0 . So the output would become

```
{
    "RequestID": "A22A8D43FE5D8D1409D5984003AB5609",
    "OPC_REQUEST_ID": [{
            "B69BF2DCEBB932A2665920BE14BA14C5": [{
                "Message": "Some message ",
                "Time": "2020-02-25T07:30:52Z",
                "bug": [
                    "27571088",
                    "7452257"
                ],
            "label": [
                    "No Label"
                ],
                "score": -0.5106
            }]
        },
        {
            "8E0FCBBF92D7226ADB6F3DB465DDA7F4": [{
                "Message": "Some message",
                "Time": "2020-02-25T07:31:52Z",
                "bug": [],
                "label": [
                    "No Label"
                ],
                "score": 0
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you edit this question with required o/p for the given doc & request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example document has `Message: "Some message"` and `Message: "Some message "` - not very obvious.

Anyway, this might be the solution:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   { RequestID: 'A22A8D43FE5D8D1409D5984003AB5609' },
   { $set: { 'OPC_REQUEST_ID.$[].8E0FCBBF92D7226ADB6F3DB465DDA7F4.$[k].score': 0 } },
   { arrayFilters: [{ 'k.Message': 'Some message' }] }
)
```

You use `A22A8D43FE5D8D1409D5984003AB5609` as a key, I don't think this is a optimal design.